# RDP con el xrdp de linuxlite

Tags: linux, rdp, linuxlite

En linux Lite, tras instalar el xrdp e iniciar sesión perfectamente con la cuenta de `root`, no consigo que el usuario `linuxlite` inicie sesión desde el cliente de RDP: simplemente me cierra la conexión sin dar ningún mensaje de error.

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 0):

Acabo de resolverlo después de reinstalar y probando la recomendación de una de las respuestas de esta [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59379842/error-when-installing-and-running-xrdp-remote-desktop-with-gnome-ubuntu-i-enc) de SO:

```
$ sudo adduser linuxlite ssl-cert
```

Espero que a alguien pueda resultarle de utilidad